# Reference request: AI panel discussion 2012

Tags: reference-request

I have seen (probably on youtube) the recording of a panel discussion at an AI conference around 2012 (year could be wrong, but close) where the audience was polled for the question of when will AI crack Go. Most of the participants predicted it would take at least decades (some thought 100+ years). Then 4 years later AlphaGo arrived. I've searched for hours, but I can't find that video. If anyone has seen it could they link it?